# Python EOFError: Ran out of input error message

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have been trying to get this dictionary to work in Python but I have failed miserably. I have found a few solutions on SO that are similar but I cannot get them to work. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way I am calling the functions. I have tried putting each piece into a separate function and that failed. I am still getting the following error message:

> employee_dictionary = pickle.load(file)
>
> EOFError: Ran out of input

Here is my code:

```
import pickle
import os.path

def main():
    employee_dictionary = {}

    if os.path.exists("employee.dat"):
        file = open("employee.dat","rb")
        employee_dictionary = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()

    else:
        emp1 = Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
        emp2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
        emp3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

        employee_dictionary = {emp1.get_ID_number(): emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp1.get_dept()+ '' + emp1.get_job_title(),\
                               emp2.get_ID_number(): emp2.get_name()+ '' + emp2.get_dept()+ '' + emp2.get_job_title(),\
                               emp3.get_ID_number(): emp3.get_name()+ '' + emp3.get_dept()+ '' + emp3.get_job_title()}

        return employee_dictionary

employee_dictionary = main()

choice = 'y'
while choice.upper()== 'Y':
    print("Make a selection from the following actions:")
    print("Lookup an employee in the dictionary: 1")
    print("Add a new employee to the dictionary: 2")
    print("Change an existing employee's name, department, and job title in the dictionary: 3")
    print("Delete an employee from the dictionary: 4")
    print("Quit the program: 5")
    selection = input("Make your selection: ")

    if int(selection) == 1:
        id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

        if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
            print(employee_dictionary[int(id_number)])

        else:
            print("The employee does not exist.")

    else:
        if int(selection) == 2:
            id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

            if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                print('That employee already exists.')

            else:
                name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp4.get_dept()+ '' + emp4.get_job_title()

                print("The employee was added.")

        else:
            if int(selection) == 3:
                id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

                if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                    name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                    dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                    title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                    emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                    employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp1.get_name()+ '' + emp4.get_dept()+ '' + emp4.get_job_title()

                    print("The employee record has been updated.")

                else:
                    print("Record not found.")

            else:
                if int(selection) == 4:
                    id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")
                    print("Deleted: ", employee_dictionary.pop(int(id_number),"Record not found."))

                else:
                    if int(selection)!=5:
                        print("")

choice = input("Do you want to make another selection (y or n)?")
file = open('employee.dat','wb')
pickle.dump(employee_dictionary,file)
file.close()
```

Here is the original Employee class:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID_number, dept, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
        self.__dept = dept
        self.__job_title = job_title

    #set methods
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_ID_number(self,ID_number):
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
    def set_dept(self,dept):
        self.__dept = dept
    def set_job_title(self,job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title


    #get methods    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID_number
    def get_dept(self):
        return self.__dept
    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.__job_title

def main():

    emp1 = Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
    emp2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
    emp3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")

    #A bunch of print statements go here

main()
```

Comment: Is there an empty `employee.dat` in the directory?. Suppose an earlier run crashed and left an empty file. You get this error the next time around. So, its partially a question of how you want to handle a corrupt .dat file. You could catch the exception, delete the file and then do the stuff in the else clause. You'll need to restructure your code a bit for that.

Comment: `file = open('employee.dat','wb')` is a bit risky. Suppose something goes wrong in the dump and you get an empty or corrupted file? You could save it to a different name and overwrite the old .dat when you know its been closed.

Comment: The problem is not with your code *per se*, but rather with the data in the file.  Has the file been modified or corrupted since it was originally pickled?  Is the version of Python that you are using the same one as the version with which the file was originally pickled?  Is the default character encoding (which you are using) the same as the encoding with which the file was originally pickled?  Did the original pickle operation fail part way through without that fact being recognized (i.e. the file was corrupt / incomplete to begin with)?

Comment: @tdelaney I will be the first to admit that my python coding abilities are less than admirable so I am not sure where it got corrupted or how to handle a corrupt .dat. I posted the original employee class that I believe the function was suppose to be calling from.

Comment: When I try to delete the employee.dat file and run it again I get a NameError: name 'Employee' is not defined message. It does not even recreate the .dat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users. I figured out a solution. Here is what I got:

```
import os.path
import pickle

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID_number, dept, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
        self.__dept = dept
        self.__job_title = job_title

    #set methods
    def set_name(self,name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_ID_number(self,ID_number):
        self.__ID_number = ID_number
    def set_dept(self,dept):
        self.__dept = dept
    def set_job_title(self,job_title):
        self.__job_title = job_title


    #get methods    
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID_number
    def get_dept(self):
        return self.__dept
    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.__job_title

def main():
    employee_dictionary = {}

    if os.path.exists("employee.dat"):
        file = open("employee.dat","rb")
        employee_dictionary = pickle.load(file)
        file.close()

    else:
        emp1 = Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, " Accounting", " Vice President")
        emp2 = Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, " IT", " Programmer")
        emp3 = Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, " Manufacturing", " Engineer")

        employee_dictionary = {emp1.get_ID_number(): emp1.get_name()+ ',' + emp1.get_dept()+ ',' + emp1.get_job_title(),\
                               emp2.get_ID_number(): emp2.get_name()+ ',' + emp2.get_dept()+ ',' + emp2.get_job_title(),\
                               emp3.get_ID_number(): emp3.get_name()+ ',' + emp3.get_dept()+ ',' + emp3.get_job_title()}

        return employee_dictionary

employee_dictionary = main()

choice = 'y'
while choice.upper()== 'Y':
    print("Make a selection from the following actions:")
    print("Lookup an employee in the dictionary: 1")
    print("Add a new employee to the dictionary: 2")
    print("Change an existing employee's name, department, and job title in the dictionary: 3")
    print("Delete an employee from the dictionary: 4")
    print("Quit the program: 5\n")
    selection = input("Make your selection: ")
    print("\n")

    if int(selection) == 1:
        id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

        if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
            print("\nThe employee is:",employee_dictionary[int(id_number)],"\n")

        else:
            print("\nThe employee does not exist.\n")

    else:
        if int(selection) == 2:
            id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

            if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                print('That employee already exists.\n')

            else:
                name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp4.get_name()+ ', ' + emp4.get_dept()+ ', ' + emp4.get_job_title()

                print("\nThe employee was added.\n")

        else:
            if int(selection) == 3:
                id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")

                if int(id_number) in employee_dictionary.keys():
                    name = input("Enter the name of the employee:")
                    dept = input("Enter the department of the employee:")
                    title = input("Enter the job title of the employee:")
                    emp4 = Employee(name,int(id_number), dept, title)
                    employee_dictionary[emp4.get_ID_number()]= emp4.get_name()+ ', ' + emp4.get_dept()+ ', ' + emp4.get_job_title()

                    print("\nThe employee record has been updated.\n")

                else:
                    print("\nRecord not found.\n")

            else:
                if int(selection) == 4:
                    id_number = input("What is the employee's ID number?")
                    print("\nDeleted: ", employee_dictionary.pop(int(id_number),"Record not found."))
                    print("\n")

                else:
                    if int(selection)!=5:
                        print("")
                    break

choice = input("Do you want to make another selection (y or n)?")
file = open('employee.dat','wb')
pickle.dump(employee_dictionary,file)
file.close()
```

Comment: Please, could you in future also add a bit of context. For example: what is the issue with original code and  why your solution is good? Thanks